# How to run Google Colab Notebook via Node.js API and Retrieving Results to Backend Server

Tags: node.js, google-colaboratory

I'm going to build a simple AI service.
I am working on a Node.js API, and I'd like to run all the code written in a Google Colab notebook and get the results on my backend server.
How can I invoke this?

Thanks in advance.